# Can ElasticSearch do a stop on first match search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a doc format like this:

```
doc #1

A: 1
B: 2
C: 3

doc #2

A: 4
B: 1
C: 8
```

So, the user input will be 1. I do a multi_match query against A,B and C. This works fine. I want to consider A as the primary, so I gave it a boost (currently 5). That works fine and all the docs with A: 1 rise to the top.

However, given the two docs above, an input of "1" will return both docs. The way I want the search to work is to make A the priority field and if I find the value there, I want to disregard the two other fields.

If no A: 1's were found, then I want to search B&C as a fallback.

Does elasticsearch have a mechanism for this?

Here are the cases for input=1

- return all A: 1 docs... if only one, then done
- if no A: 1 docs, or multiple A: 1 docs, also include B: 1 and C: 1 docs

Comment: You need to think about this from Elasticsearch point of view. Controlling such things in ES is all about scoring. You can use `"size":1` to only return one documents. You can boost specific documents so that you can decide which comes before others. Maybe you can do it like this. But if think about this use case like the programming approach (if then else) that won't work with ES, as @imotov mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch doesn't support such functionality. Even if it did, it wouldn't be significantly more optimal then you running the first query against A and if it doesn't return anything running the second query against B and C from the client.

In elasticsearch, search is distributed across multiple shards and the fact that a particular shard didn't find a document doesn't mean that this document doesn't exist in other shards. So, to implement it inside elasticsearch, we would have to execute the query for A first, check that it doesn't return anything and then execute the query for B and C. Moving this to the client just adds an additional hop between the client and the elasticsearch node to the process. Other than that, it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was toying with running a *single* query against A,B,C and boosting A to bring it to the top. It is not possible to have multiple A:1's, so the client would just need to check the first record to see if it was matched on A and then discard the rest. But that would still match against A,B,C all the time and do the filtering in the app. So its either 2 queries with the first possibly being "lighter". Or just 1 and do the check in the app.